# Is it possible to get a last-update timestamp for a table column IMPLICITLY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp, h2

I googled around and found no answer. The question is whether for an existing SQL table (assume any of H2, MySQL, or Postgres)...

**Is there a way to get the last-update timestamp value for a given table row. That is, without explicitly declaring a new column (altering the table), and/or adding triggers that update a timestamp column.**

I'm using a JDBC driver, preparing statements, getting ResultSets and so forth. I need to be able to determine whether the data has changed recently or not, and for this a timestamp would help. If possible I want to avoid adding timestamp columns across all tables in the system.

Comment: Are you able to create a trigger on the table? If so, you would be able to keep track of any updates/inserts by having the trigger save that information in another table. If not, you may be able to find out by accessing the logs (if they are enabled for that level of detail) - it would require more work, but you may be able to get the information you need from it.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was something more standard. Going the logs route is non performant and database specific, so it impacts portability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit standard approach to this problem. The standard way is having an explicit column and logic in a db trigger or app function... 
As mentioned, there are ways to do it through the logs but it's hard and usually wont be much accurate. For example, in Postgres you can enable commit timestamps in postgresql.conf and check the last update time but those are approximate and are not kept for a long time...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Everything you have written was discussed and acknowledged already in the comments, so I am not sure what value this adds.